# Update document in MongoDB with unique compound index

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, upsert, compound-index

I have a document in MongoDB with unique compound index.

```
@Document
@CompoundIndex(def = "{'field1':1, 'field2':1", unique = true)
public class MyClass implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private Field1 field1;

    private Field2 field2

...
}
```

I use `Spring Data`. Whenever I try to save a document with both values duplicated, I get `E11000 duplicate key error` with an appropriate Duplicate Key Exception.

I want to make MongoDB **replace** the record in case of duplication instead of throwing an exception. But both MongoRepository methods like `save` and `insert` are of no help. Is there any way to do what I want?

Comment: if you want to replace, what is the point in creating an index? You create an index to avoid overwriting

Comment: Because there are a lot of other fields that may be different, and this index is not a primary key.